# How to Setting Gradle Wrapper in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, homebrew

why after, I downloaded gradle version 6.3, my android studio wanted to download version 5.4.1.

why is that, even though I have downloaded gradle version 6.3.

Please help me

i use android studio version : 3.5.2

the link below is a screenshot of my android version
https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Tg6.png

the link below is a screenshot of my android preference
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzPGR.png

this is my directory file path screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmKl2.png

this is a screenshot when my android studio is downloading gradle 5.4.1
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnka7.png

this is my gradle version in terminal
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGLKD.png

this is my java version in terminal
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpjqs.png

this is my javac version in the terminal
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yklq6.png

this is my homebrew version in the terminal
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBhZ0.png

Answer (score 0):

If your `gradle-wrapper.properties` specifies gradle version 5.4.1, your Android Studio would download the version.

[image]

And I don't know the Android Studio v3.5.2 can use gradle v6.3. As of my Android Studio v3.6.3, it seems gradle v5.6.4 is the default.

Comment: thak you for your answer